# Print the middle integer from a list of sorted numbers

Tags: python

> Given a sorted list of integers, output the middle integer. Assume the number of integers is always odd

Input: `2 3 4 8 11`

Output: `4`

This is what I have so far

```
inputs=[]

num_inputs=int(input())

if(num_inputs>9):
    print("Too many inputs")
else:
    print(num_inputs)
    for i in range(num_inputs):
        inputs.append(input())
    print(inputs)
    middle_position=int(num_inputs/2)
    print(inputs[middle_position])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input is only one line of data.

To read that into a list, you would use

```
inputs = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Or just `inputs = input.split()` since you don't need ints

Then you would just need to check `len(inputs) > 9` and get `inputs[len(inputs) // 2]`. No loops